# How insert UUID values in PostgreSQL table via Kettle?

Tags: postgresql, etl, kettle

My Kettle Transformation looks simple. "Table Input --> Table output". In table input block: simple SQL statement which works fine on server.

When i'm trying to insert UUID value to PostgreSQL table via Kettle i have error:

```
ERROR: column "UUID_Col1" is of type uuid but expression is of type character varying
```

I found [this](http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?133546-ERROR-column-quot-guid-quot-is-of-type-uuid-but-expression-is-of-type-character-varying) solution. But then i faced another problem. Looks like parmeter "stringtype=unspecified" work only for first column. 
After setting parameter error:

```
 ERROR: column "UUID_Col2" is of type uuid but expression is of type character varying
```

Table looks like:

```
     "Date"                 TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE
    ,"CharNum"              VARCHAR(10)
    ,"UUID_Col1"            UUID
    ,"ЦентрПрибыли"         VARCHAR(80)
    ,"UUID_Col2"            UUID
    ,"UUID_Col3"            UUID
    ,"VarcharCol1"          VARCHAR(100)
    ,"VarcharCol2"          VARCHAR(100)
```

Comment: Can you show the `INSERT` statement? The solution is likely to add casts.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I'm using this block.  http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Table+Output    . And the SQL statement is hidden for me. For now i made solutinon with PostgreSQL function. It work for current task. Still i want to solve this problem.

Comment: @user3627830 I think in the thread you provided a guy named thomasperrin also had the same issue when one of the uuid is a primary key and others not. Cos it works fine if all 3 uuids are not primary keys.

Answer (score 2):

(old thread but putting this here just because it is a top google result for this problema)

using this solution
http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?133546-ERROR-column-quot-guid-quot-is-of-type-uuid-but-expression-is-of-type-character-varying
fixed the issue for me (pentaho 7.1, postgresql 9.6).
on the connection window, options, and set 
stringtype=unspecified

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTjFV.jpg)

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: thank you @BaummitAugen

but I included a screenshot and even the solution is described in text. but ok.

Comment: I tried this but this is not working for me. I am still getting error of column being of type uuid while value is of type character varying.