# Pentaho select UUID type fild as UUID and Insert into other table as UUID

Tags: postgresql, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I am new to Pentaho, my research end up with nothing
I have a table that has filed with type UUID
I need to copy it to another table where the field has the same UUID.
Table input. has this SQL
[image]

I am casting field to UUI filed specifically.
however when I check input fields on the output table it shows as string, how do I cast it to uuid.

[image]

Also the same for the output table, it was created with datatype UUID for that field

[image]

output table shows datatype as the string

[image]

On the run, it throws an error clearly showing that it cannot convert it to UUID

```
2022/02/11 10:42:45 - Table output.0 - Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "qr_uuid" is of type uuid but expression is of type character varying
```

I am using Postgres 13 and Pentaho 9

Answer (score 2):

I have found an old thread dealing with the same problem, and there are some hints for the answer. You'll need to edit the database connection for postgres, and in the *Options* menu add Parameter **stringtype** with Value **unspecified**:

[How insert UUID values in PostgreSQL table via Kettle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38563544/how-insert-uuid-values-in-postgresql-table-via-kettle)

Comment: my solution was to change UUID to text on select and it was inserted into the UUID column with no error, don't know why its doing it , but its working

Comment: How did you achieve that?

Comment: I tried this but I am getting same issue.